# "Origin non null" from this JavaScript: why?

Tags: jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-Domain Requests with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638773/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery)

```
$(function () {
    (function getFeed() {
        $
            .get('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/rss.xml')
            .done(function (feed) {
                console.info('\Feed received: ', feed);
                displayProgrammes(feed);
            })
            .fail(function () {
                console.info('\nError getting the feed.');
            })
    }());
});
```

It's a simple Ajax request, nothing more. And yet I get the error message:

> Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Can you please let us now what you are trying to do?

Comment: It's a simple *cross-domain* Ajax request which isn't possible out of the box.

Comment: @campino2k: I'm trying to extract the XML from the feed!

Comment: @Pekka: The feed is designed for external use!

Comment: @Random that doesn't matter, it's a browser side security mechanism.

Comment: @Randomblue: use a server side action (php, ruby, whatever) to access crossdomain or check if they offer a JSONP-Interface.

Comment: @Pekka: Check out http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/10628494#userss for the paragraph "Using BBC news feeds on your site"

Comment: You could try this: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/11/cross-domain-rss-to-json-converter.html

Comment: @Random so? It doesn't matter whether they are okay with it or not. As said, it's a browser side security mechanism, limited to JavaScript. It has nothing to do with the BBC at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requests in AJAX can only be made to the same domain, this is called the Same Origin Policy ->

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

(Example of a way around this issue using PHP as a proxy : http://devtreats.blogspot.com/search/label/ajax)

**There is another way .... YQL ->
[Cross-Domain Requests with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638773/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery)**