# (jquery) .load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to load an external website using .load function?

```
<div id="new"></div>
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#new").load("http://omn.orgfree.com/");
    })

</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you run the code to see if it's possible?

Comment: Try it first. Then dig in and try to find out why it didn't work. Look at Firebug and Chrome debugger tools. You'll likely have more specific questions by that point, and those would be great edits to this one. This is a good start to a fine question, but it definitely needs more research and details. Good luck!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross+domain+ajax

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-Domain Requests with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638773/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

Due to browser's [same origin restrictions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you cannot load content with ajax from other domains.

You could display that content in an iframe or you could use a server proxy in your own domain to fetch the content for you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your expectations. If you want to maintain the capability to traverse and manipulate DOM of the loaded page, then the short answer is "no" due to cross-domain security policies.

You could still commonly integrate the content by using an iframe or a more compliant `<object data="http://omn.orgfree.com/" type="text/html" />`, and there are protocols like [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) allowing client-side cross-domain communication. Integration has to be done by both parties though.

Again, assuming that the other party is available to assist with integration or you have direct control over the other domain's content, you could use [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) with ajax requests - technically any html could be serialized that way.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. User can load only those web pages that are within its directory.
However this feature can be achieved through server side methods(in case of c#).