# http $.post from android does not work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, android-emulator

Asp.net page with jquery 1.7.1  When I post it from an Android phone via an emulator in Eclipse the post without the http://www.somedomain.com/ works perfectly.  If i include the http url it does not work.  The insert into the database is fine with wfo_s.aspx but not with http://www.somedomain.com/wfo_s.aspx

If anyone can shed some light on why this is happening, I would really appreciate it.  Thanks!

```
//this does not work?
//$.post("http://www.somedomain.com/wfo_s.aspx", { the_User: theheatmap, conn: db_connection }, function (data) { });
//$.post("http://www.somedomain.com/wfo_s.aspx?the_User=" + theheatmap + "&conn=" + db_connection);
//this does work, why does the post to the url not work, page works fine 
//$.post("wfo_s.aspx", { the_User: theheatmap, conn: db_connection }, function (data) { });
//$.post("wfo_s.aspx?the_User=" + theheatmap + "&conn=" + db_connection);
```

Comment: Most probably `http://www.somedomain.com` is not the same server (domain, sub domain and protocol) as the one that served the current page.

Comment: Maybe it won't work because it is all commented out?

Comment: Tested locally or on the remote server, the http url from android emulator does not post to database.  But when i just use wfo_s.aspx... it works perfectly?  If I run the same code on my regular laptop both methods work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-Domain Requests with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638773/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery) ok well nevermind this is not the case I suppose.

Comment: are you sure you are not trying to connect (locally) to http://localhost.com???

Comment: @rlemon who connects to localhost.com? :-P

Comment: yes not localhost.  I can see the remote database being updated with wfo_s.aspx post either from my local visual studio or running it from the server.

Comment: locally or remote ... this does not matter! The only thing that counts is that the server that served the current page must(!) be `http://www.somedomain.com`

Comment: @Neal who tries to make cross domain XHR requests? :P

Comment: @Rob does your dev tools (chrome) network tab show any 4xx or 5xx errors? This will tell you if the issues are with finding the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!  I was testing Android 1.5 and then loaded Android 2.1 and the post now works.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** do ajax requests cross site.

There are some hacks (eg: `jsonp`) but not with regular requests.