# load and ajax not working as alternative to iframe...giving error js disabled

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-load

i'm loading a site "B", which is using canvas, into site 'A'. iframe was an easy option and is working great but i want to do it using jQuery. I tried using ".load" and "$.ajax" the site "B" is giving error javascript is disabled on your browser...below is the code...

if i directly load that site into another window it works well..I do not want to use iframe .. i need to load it in some div

```
    using .load...
    $("#dataLoader").load('http://www.xyz.com');

    and using ajax...
    $.ajax({
         url: "http://www.xyz.com",
        cache: false
         }).done(function( html ) {
                         console.log(html)
                       $("#dataLoader").append(html);
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This cannot be done without an iFrame.** iFrames are specifically built to load pages. `ajax` cannot be used for content-injection from cross domains. There are many alternatives/fixes to rectify this :

- As the previous answer has recommended, set the `url` attribute of the iframe to the target page and be done with it.
- If the url isnt dynamic, just set the `src` attribute within the HTML itself. No jQuery would be needed then.
- You could use `jsop` *if* `cors` is supported by the server on which `xyz.com` is hosted on.
- If you're still insistent on using `ajax` and jquery for this, use this extra mod to the `ajax` library : http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/
- There's one last (and more complicated) way to achive this. You could send a request to your server and make the server talk to the url and then make your server return it to you. You could use `ajax` to get that out.

Please look at these links for more clarity on this :

- [Ajax/jQuery - Load webpage content into a div on page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load)
- http://davescoolblog.blogspot.in/2012/02/client-side-cross-domain-data-yql-hack.html
- [Cross-Domain Requests with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638773/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery)

Comment: welcome :) please upvote the answer if you think it has helped you and if you think it'll help others later :)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `src` attribute of the iframe. Something like

```
$("#frame").attr("src", url);
```