# jQuery / JSON unable to call an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I'm attempting to utilise the web service at Glosbe.com/a-api using jQuery. Could anyone tell me why my code below isn't returning any results? I am looking to query the API at Glosbe with a word and have the definition of that word displayed below.

Thanks.

This is the jQuery I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#term').focus(function(){
  var full = $("#poster").has("img").length ? true : false;
  if(full === false){
     $('#poster').empty();
  }
});

var getPoster = function(){

    var film = $('#term').val();

     if(film === ''){

        $('#poster').html("<h2 class='loading'>Ha! We haven't forgotten to validate the form! Please enter something.</h2>");

     } else {

        $('#poster').html("<h2 class='loading'>Your definition is on its way!</h2>");

        $.getJSON("http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=hello&pretty=true" + film + "?callback=?", function(json) {
           if (json !== "Nothing found."){
                 $('#poster').html('<h2 class="loading">Well, gee whiz! We found you a definition, skip!</h2><img id="thePoster" src=' + json[0].posters[0].image.url + ' />');
              } else {
                 $.getJSON("http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=hello&pretty=true" + "?callback=?", function(json) {
                    console.log(json);
                    $('#poster').html('<h2 class="loading">Nothing found.</h2><img id="thePoster" src=' + json[0].posters[0].image.url + ' />');
                 });
              }
         });

      }

    return false;
};

$('#search').click(getPoster);
$('#term').keyup(function(event){
   if(event.keyCode === 13){
       getPoster();
   }
});

});
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Matthew Hughes">
    <meta name="Dictionary" content="A dictionary web service">
    <title>Dictionary Web Application</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--jQuery, linked from a CDN-->
    <script src="dictionary.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://use.typekit.com/oya4cmx.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Dictionary Application</h1>
        </header>
        <section id="fetch">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a word..." id="term" />
            <button id="search">Define!</button>
        </section>
        <section id="poster">
        </section>
        <footer>
            <p>Created by Matthew Hughes</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are attempting a cross domain request.  [See this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7638786/1430708)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll try to make a request, you'll get `400 Bad request` error. Take a look on URL at your code:

```
http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase=hello&pretty=true" + film + "?callback=?"
```

You've made a typo, and the correct URL should be

```
http://glosbe.com/gapi/translate?from=eng&dest=eng&format=json&phrase="+ film + "&pretty=true&callback=?"
```

jQuery automatically detects "callback=?" and switching to JSONP format. This works fine for me. But please be aware that response has no `posters` field.

Comment: Will this work? Or will I still have the issue with the cross domain requesting? Is there any easy work around for that?

Comment: That works perfectly! What would be the easiest way to clean up the JSON output? And can you show me what I did wrong?

Comment: @Spencer You've just made wrong concatenation, value of `film` variable was appended to the `pretty=true`. What do you mean by `clean up the JSON output`?

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the explanation. Currently the JSOn output I receive back from Glosbe is just a huge block of JSON? Is there any way to clean it up and make it more readable output?

Comment: @Spencer well, it's on your own how you'll parse it.

Answer (score 1):

Because It is a cross domain call. Browser will block it because of **same origin policy**.
If you are trying to make cross domain ajax, you should CORS in your ajax. Server should also enabled it. Another method for cross domain ajax is using jsonp.

Comment: could you please explain what does json do.